# Python secure subprocess call

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, python-os

I'm trying to use subprocess to call user programs. Right now I'm trying to use `subprocess.Popen` with `preexec_fn` calling `os.setuid` and `os.chroot` to sandbox the user code, but I'm running into permission issues. `Operation not permitted`. I saw some code samples do similar things but for some reason I'm running into issues.

Comment: Code needs to be running as a privileged user to invoke those calls; thus, setuid can only be used to _decrease_ privileges, not _increase_ them. If your code is in fact running as root already, check its capability set -- dropping capabilities is often used to reduce the potential damage a subverted process can do if it's running as root.

Comment: In general, a good place to start here is the manual for the underlying syscalls or C library functions; typically that documentation will list the failure modes that lead to each error.

Comment: (another possibility is syscall filters or security layers like SELinux, which can restrict the range of actions a process is allowed to take; there are enough possible ways a system can be configured to disallow these calls it's not really possible to provide a comprehensive list)

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want to refine the question, a good place to start would be to show enough code, and enough details about the reproduction environment, to let someone else reproduce the problem so answers can be tested.

Comment: @Johnsyweb, are you sure this is a duplicate? I'm not using my own dupehammer to reopen it right now because I think it runs afoul of other criteria for topicality (lacking a [mre] or other details needed sufficient to allow tested answers), but the OP states that they _are_ using `subprocess.Popen`, and that the problems they're having relate to sandboxing the called process via a calling same with a `preexec_fn` callback that drops privileges; that's not exactly consistent with being a duplicate of a "don't know what `subprocess.Popen` is" beginner question.